# how to set activiti form(from xml file) properties for jsf pages

Tags: activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

I am new to activiti work flow
I am doing a project with activiti-cdi and jsf. 
how to use the form properties in activiti designer to render jsf form elements?
or
how a form will be rendered with Activiti Explorer?
i need to indicate form(by defining form properties on a start event or a user task)in my jsf page
what is the best way to do it ?
please help ...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to link those things together in your own internal layer.